# Is it possible to inverse selection in Object mode?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

I imported a 3D apartment model from an Archicad .3ds file.

Scale and coordinates were all messed up and I solved this by resetting location, scale, rotation and origin. Now the model seems fine except that when I press "zoom to all" it zooms out so much that the screen is empty. I figure that there must be something left to original imported scale (0.000001) that is causing this. To find it I planned to select everything visible on my scene and invert selection. Just can't seem to find the function. (The scene has over 250 objects.)

Comment: Upload your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so others can take a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert a selection.

Comment: Ctrl + i worked great, thanks! There was a "Lamp" object still an impossible amount of distance away, resetting it fixed my problem :)